# Pubg: lost 50% of my crates with update #1.0

Tags: xbox-one, pubg-battlegrounds

I had 15 crates in my Playerunknowns Battlegrounds account (Xbox One) before the update 1.0. I am sure because I wanted to reach to 25 crates to make an streaming with my friends for the unboxing.

After the update, 8 crates disappeared. Weeks of play gone down the trash.

Is there a limit of crates with the update? Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: They returned all the crates to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to a some sort of bug in the game.  The Survivor and Wanderer crates have dissappeared from players inventories.  [This article](https://www.dbltap.com/posts/6165736-missing-survivor-and-wanderer-crates-will-be-fixed-for-pubg-xbox-next-week) states:

> ​​The Survivor and Wanderer crates disappeared from ​PUBG Xbox players' inventories after PUBG 1.0 went live. "We have investigated reports of Survivor and Wanderer Crates disappearing from the inventory. The Item IDs of these crates were changed with the 1.0 launch, which caused this issue to occur for players who purchased these crates pre-1.0

The article quotes this information from an [official Reddit Post](https://old.reddit.com/r/PUBGXboxOne/comments/9e14n7/community_weekly_post_september_week_1/) made by PUBG.  According to that post, they intend to deploy a fix for this sometime within the week.